# Estimate web app resource usage in preparation for understanding pricing for a cloud migration

Tags: cloud, pricing, cpu, google-cloud, memory

I'm currently using VPS to host my web app which price is fixed per month. I read about cloud services such as Google Cloud Platform and their pricing is based on resources usage. How can I know how many resources does my app use?

I'm not sure but I think that memory and CPU usage is the thing to calculate usage. I probably know CPU usage time of my app since I started it via htop command on linux, but how can I know memory usage per day if it's even included in cloud pricing. I don't fully understand how the cloud pricing system works.

My web app is spring boot app.

Comment: I'm not sure about Google, but with Amazon, you don't get charged for CPU and memory used.  You have to pick an appropriately sized instance up front, just like you would have to do when you chose your VPS.   The biggest difference is that you get charged per hour of instance use rather than for the month of a VPS.  You do get charged for some resources like bandwidth.